View for hosted raster service on ArcGIS Enterprise Portal
ArcGIS Portal has Hosted Feature Layer Views. These are super useful because they allow you to host one vector dataset and then display that dataset in multiple (well – 20) different ways. Portal users can then easily add these views to their maps. What is the equivalent for a HOSTED raster dataset (e.g. a Map Image Layer)?
Use case: We want to host a categorical (thematic) raster dataset with an attribute table in our Portal data store. Let’s say the National Land Cover Dataset for example. We then want to display that data in different ways with views of the one hosted raster dataset. One display could be all cover types. Another display could be just the “Developed” cover types.
Issue: There does not seem to be a way create views for any of the hosted raster solutions. Am I missing something?
Open to workarounds so long as the raster data ends up hosted in our Portal data store and not duplicated.

The way you describe MapServer sounds like the option to "reference registered data". If so, that is not what I am trying to do. We have a requirement that the dataset is hosted in the Portal data store (the "copy all data" option).
With ImageServer, I understand that there are processing/analytics available. But I am not finding anything regarding attribute based symbology.
